# Cannot access vhost in windows

Tags: xampp

Adding a new vhost is a 2-step process.

Add new entry in the hosts file in C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts:

**127.0.0.1     my.dev**

and a new entry in C:\env\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/env/workspace/mydev"
    ServerName my.dev

    <Directory "C:/env/workspace/mydev">
        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

But when I type my.dev into my browser I only get a "not found" page.
In the network tab of firebug the status is "aborted".

For testing I deactivated my firewall and my antivirus software and still
get the same "not found" page.

I have no idea what could be the problem.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Deleted the hosts file, created a new one and typed my entries.
And now it works. Maybe the hosts file was saved in a wrong format?